# Website UN and PW Automation getting into website

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

What I am trying to do is automate a login for a specific website. The only thing I am having trouble with is figuring out how to make it enter into the website once it populates my UN and PW.

How do I make this script advance into the website?

[image: This is the button I want to make the script press or just having it bring me into the full website.]

```
$username = "XXXX";
$password = "XXX:)";
$loginUrl = "https://example.com";
$iterator = 1;

#initialize browser
$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application;
$ie.visible = $true;
$ie.navigate($loginUrl);
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1; }    #wait for browser idle
($ie.document.getElementsByName("username") |select -first 1).value = $username;
($ie.document.getElementsByName("password") |select -first 1).value = $password;
($ie.document.getElementsByName("login") |select -first 1).click();
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1; }    #wait for browser idle
```